# Booting from Xubuntu 15.04 installation media hangs when booting with UEFI

Tags: fedora, uefi, efi, xubuntu

I want to dual boot my laptop with Windows 10 and Linux. I'm attempting to install `Xubuntu 15.04 x64` but when I boot from the installation media it hangs on `starting version 219` then eventually my caps lock LED starts flashing and it reboots... rinse and repeat.

I've tried booting from CD and USB, both hang in the same spot. I've tried disabling `secure boot` and it still hangs. The only thing I can get to work is if I enable `UEFI with CSM (Compatibility Support Module)`, then the installation media will boot and I can start the install.

I would prefer to not have `CSM` enabled since Xubuntu 15.04 claims to work with EFI and I would like to use EFI only. Anyone know what the deal is?

The laptops specs are as follows in case that might have something to do with it:

- Intel i7 5th gen processor
- 64 gigs system ram
- 2x Nvidia GeForce 980M with 8 gigs each
- Mostly SSDs configured in RAID 0 (Stripe)
- Secure Boot Enabled
- Fast Boot Disabled
- UEFI Enabled
- Windows 10 installed (was installed with UEFI enabled)
- Windows 10 Fast Startup is disabled
- Windows Boot Manager has lowest priority on boot

**UPDATE**

I tried the same things as above but with `Fedora 22` and it produced the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this same question on the Ubuntu forums and was given an [answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2292429&p=13346125#post13346125).

Basically just press 'e' on the grub menu while having the boot option selected that you want to use. Replace "quite splash" with "nomodeset" and press Ctrl+x or F10 to boot with the new options. This worked for me perfectly.

Comment: `e` does not have an effect at mine

Comment: @PeterRader Sounds like you might need to open a new question for that. From [here](http://grumpymole.blogspot.com/2007/05/ubuntu-how-to-edit-grub-boot-parameters.html): When the PC boots up, you will see the Grub countdown, which is set to 3 seconds by default. Press "Esc" to intercept this countdown and go enter a Grub menu. Then press 'e' to start editing.